# Trigger Chrome extension on new tab open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to run Chrome extension when new tab is opened and html document is loaded.

*Extension needs to check for new tab title and if it's equal to predefined string, tab should close.*

For now, I have manage to write extension that works when I click on it's icon. But I want to make it to run without click on icon after the page is loaded in new tab.

Here is the current code.

```
function getCurrentTabData(callback) {
  var queryInfo = {
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  };
  chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    var title = tab.title;
    var id = tab.id;
    callback(title, id);
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  getCurrentTabData(function(title, id) {

    if(title == 'Page title') {
        chrome.tabs.remove(id, function() { });
    }

  });
});
```

And here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Auto close tab",
  "description": "Auto closes tab if title is matched",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

How to make it run without click on it's icon?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To accomplish this first of all you will need to have a Background Page that will manage your extension state. You can read about it here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

Then in the background page script you will need to listen when the tab is created with this piece of code:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function callback)
```

Here is documentation for this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated

Hope this will help to solve your issue.

Comment: is there a way to change the content of the "new tab page" to your own page?