# How to set a javascript file in chrome,when ever I open a new window it will automatically get execute?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My js file contains some userid and password.I want to set as a prompt for new tab.

Comment: There are certain user extensions that will execute arbitrary scripts in the browser. For creating one yourself you can see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067198/trigger-chrome-extension-on-new-tab-open

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bookmark,

press `ctrl+D` in the name section, `javascript: #your script`

refer this [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)

I used to load script in this way for eg: Tatkal ticket booking, etc...